# Highcharts - Update column chart in real time

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm trying to update dynamically a `column` type Highcarts with no luck. This is the demo code for the `column` chart:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
            max: 100
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}m/s²rms'
            }
        }
    },    
    "series": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "colorByPoint": true,
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "y": 30
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

I would like to update the `y` value dynamically. I tried to add this on the `charts` section of the JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',

        // This is my new code to update Y every second
        load : function() {
          var series = this.series[0];
          setInterval(function() {
            y = Math.random();
            series.data.y([y]);
          }, 1000);
        }
        // End of my new code
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    }, 
[...]
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/af8p9yon/

Can someone tell me how can I archieve this with Javascript? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your code, there is no `events` property and you should use `setData` or `update` method:

using setData method

```
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var series = this.series[0];
            setInterval(function() {
                y = Math.random();
                series.setData([y]);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

using update method

```js
events: {
  load: function() {
    var series = this.series[0];
    setInterval(function() {
      y = Math.random() * 100;
      series.update({
        data: [y],
      }, true)
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Louath3b/

API:

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly! It's another question, but its possible to change the color of the chart there too? Something like `series.setColor("#ffffff")`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Avión, yes of course, the best will be `update` method: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sk3706rf/

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're my hero of today :D my last question, is there a way to make a _smoother_ animation when the change of the data? https://jsfiddle.net/af8p9yon/3/

Comment: I am glad I could help. Here is an example with animation: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uvpdxz24/

Comment: @ppotaczek what is the property or option you add to keep the animation consistent when you update the chart? I used the update method in this example https://jsfiddle.net/iamarasekera/0Lqc3ema/5/ but when I update the colors they do not animate.

Comment: @ppotaczek I modified your fiddle to update the columns with different colours. Even in that the animation does not work now. Check this out. https://jsfiddle.net/iamarasekera/paj4hsgb/3/ I think may be the animation only works when the columns are updated with the same colour.

Comment: @Ishara Amarasekera, The update animation is improved on the Highcharts master branch and it will be available in the next release: https://jsfiddle.net/v5L2mx63/ For more information, you can check this issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10216

Comment: @ppotaczek this looks great. Can I use this in my current project? When will this be released? And if I use this and when the next release comes, it will only be a matter of changing the url, won't it?

Comment: @Ishara Amarasekera, Yes, you can, but it is not officially supported. Highcharts 7.1 is planned for Q1 2019. And yes, the url change will be enough.